# Force Upsource to update commit name

Tags: svn, jetbrains-ide, upsource

I use SVN with JetBrains Upsource.

I wrote down a wrong commit message and it was uploaded on Upsource. Then I changed commit name but Upsource didn't update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately for now there no possibility to update commit message in Upsource.
There's [feature request in tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/UP-4771), please vote/watch.